# Symfony 5 and webpack encore in prod env : avoid hash string in build filename

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony5, webpack-encore

When I run the command `yarn build`, some files are created in the `public/build` directory, generated files get a new filename containing a random hash string :

[image]

For **only** files themes/light and theme/dark I need to remove automatically the random hash string when I run the `yarn build`, I want to keep the original filename. I mean, currently the command generate theses files :

- public/build/themes/light.3ac94fb2.css
- public/build/themes/dark.064ff2f6.css

And instead, I want to have :

- public/build/themes/light.css
- public/build/themes/dark.css

Is it possible to do that automatically ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack configuration: remove hash from \*.js entry/bundle files names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044219/webpack-configuration-remove-hash-from-js-entry-bundle-files-names)

Comment: I wouldn't do it though, because this is a nice [cache busting](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/#changing-file-name) technique and doing without it can cause you big troubles

Comment: thank for your quickly help ! I want remove the hash on only specifics generated files (not all), and I use Encore with webpack. Your help is a track, but Im not sure its sufficient

Comment: *I want remove the hash on only specifics generated files (not all)* > This is a very important piece of information and should be [edit]ed in your question along with the pattern of what should and should not include the hash

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having the files twice, one with the hash, one without, then the `copyFiles` plugin is probably the way to go:

This work adding, in your `Encore` configuration in *webpack.config.js* something like:

```js
Encore
    // Your usual config comes here

    .copyFiles([
        {
            from: './assets/themes/light.css', 
            // or wherever the file lives in the assets folder
            to: 'public/build/themes/light.css'
        },{
            from: './assets/themes/dark.css',
            // or wherever the file lives in the assets folder
            to: 'public/build/themes/dark.css'
        }
    ])
;
```

<sup>*Notice: untested – find more explanation here: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/copy-files*</sup>

There is also a [`configureFilenames`](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/5bd915246dff3427033509e9c459a48d6c173b93/lib/WebpackConfig.js#L853) function, but I am not sure you'll be able to fit conditionals in it.